# What XFS configuration should I use for EC2 disks (mysql db-server)

Tags: configuration, amazon-ec2, xfs

To be able to use ec2-consistent-snapshot on my EC2 servers I have decided to make my partition for my database data XFS

What are the best XFS configuration options I can use for these disk? The disk will be around 5-10 Gb big, containing 1 Gb of database. I am looking for both the best options when creating the filesystem as the mounting in fstab.

The operating system I use is Ubuntu Server 10.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, I'd recommend using [ec2-consistent-snapshot](https://launchpad.net/ec2-consistent-snapshot). It builds on XFS' snapshotting. Then there's [a blog post](http://alestic.com/2009/09/ec2-consistent-snapshot) explaining the ideas and usage.

A lot of people recommend to use `noatime` in `/etc/fstab` -- but besides I'm not aware of any magic switches.

Somewhat related: http://shlomoswidler.com/2010/01/creating-consistent-snapshots-of-live.html

Explains how you can leverage the above to use the tool on a EBS-based AMI's root file system. Maybe that provides more pointers?

**Edit**

I don't think you'll gain a lot more by tweaking xfs. For starters, EBS is a network file system with sometimes very flakey performance. I have never seen a constant read/write throughput ever. XFS or any other file system cannot do much about it.

I also wouldn't select XFS for sole performance reasons. I'd select it for the snapshot capability see the above links (about `ec2-consistent-snapshot` and related). That's the exciting part.

Also, you will gain more performance by [setting up a raid of EBS volumes](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2009/08/06/ec2ebs-single-and-raid-volumes-io-bencmark/) than by playing with XFS parameters. I still use the XFS defaults on a larger MySQL setup.

Generally, performance improves with the instance type used (e.g. small is worse than an L because of the network interface and EBS is basically network storage).

For the OS, I'd use Karmic (9.10). I didn't find 10.04 or 10.10 to be really stable.

Last but not least -- with 5 GB you should not run into any issues. Is your data expected to grow fast? If capacity planing is an issue and you require absolute availability I'd also recommend checking into [RDS](http://aws.amazon.com/rds/) as they provide a hosted MySQL server and multi-zone is an option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I was more searching for general things like xfs logfile size... noatime is on the list

Comment: I can't edit my answer. Serverfault dies.

Comment: Ok, extended my answer.